# React JS set state only works for the previous item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React JS.

I got the following code:

```
const [tags, setTags] = React.useState([]);
```

And there are some labels. If you click on a label, then this will happen:

```
    const handleClick = (e) => {
      setTags([...tags, e]);
      console.log(tags)
```

"e" comes as a String, which is the label's value

But my problem is with setTags, it does not add the current "e" to the tags array. The console log line will come empty for the first execution of handleClick.

If I click another label, then the console log will print an array which contains the PREVIOUSLY clicked label, but not the current one. I dont understand this behavior.

Comment: state is updated asynchronously, that's why logging `tags` right after `setTags` function call will always give you the previous value. To see the updated value of `tags`, use `useEffect` hook that runs whenever `tags` is changed.

Comment: check value from "e"

Comment: React state updates are asynchronous. You can't immediately see the updates (console.log) after **setTags**

Answer (score 0):

React state updates are asynchronous.
By adding an useEffect hook with a dependency on tags, I have managed to obtain what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

State updates are asynchronous in react. Try this:

```js
const [tags, setTags] = React.useState([]);

const handleClick = (e) => {
  setTags([...tags, e]);
}

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(tags);
});
```